# Javascript blockquote fade

Tags: javascript

So i was looking around the questions and found this handy piece of code that i want to use.

```
function fade() {

var op = 1;  // initial opacity
var thing = document.getElementById('fader');
var timer = setInterval(function () 
{

    if (op <= 0.1)
    {
        clearInterval(timer);
        thing.style.display = 'none';
    }

    thing.style.opacity = op;
    thing.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
    op -= op * 0.1;
}, 50); 


}

function unfade() {

var thing2 = document.getElementById('fader');
var op = 0.1;  // initial opacity
thing2.style.display = 'block';
var timer = setInterval(function () {

    if (op >= 1){
        clearInterval(timer);
    }

    thing2.style.opacity = op;
    thing2.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
    op += op * 0.1;
    //alert("here");
}, 10);

}
```

Can how these functions exactly works be explained a little bit? I mainly wanted to play around with it to get something to fade in and out from view. Could I link the code to a button that, when clicked, fade a blockquote with the id of 'fader' from view, but have both of these functions go once i just click the one button?

Edit: I played around with some code so i ended up with a test code like this.

```
<!doctype HTML>

<html>

<head>

<style>

    blockquote{

        max-height: auto;
        max-width: auto;
        position: fixed;
        right: 50%;
        bottom: 50%;
        border-style: ridge;
        border-width: 5px;
        padding: 25px;


    }

    </style>

    </head>


<body>
<form>

    <blockquote id= 'fader'> 

        <input type = 'button' id = 'fades' value = 'This fades.' onclick = 'fade(); unfade()'/>

    </blockquote>

</form>


</body>

<script>



    function fade() {

    var op = 1;  // initial opacity
    var thing = document.getElementById('fader');
    var timer = setInterval(function () 
    {

        if (op <= 0.1)
        {
            clearInterval(timer);
            thing.style.display = 'none';
        }

        thing.style.opacity = op;
        thing.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
        op -= op * 0.1;
    }, 50); 


}

    function unfade() {

    var thing2 = document.getElementById('fader');
    var op = 0.1;  // initial opacity
    thing2.style.display = 'block';
    var timer = setInterval(function () {

        if (op >= 1){
            clearInterval(timer);
        }

        thing2.style.opacity = op;
        thing2.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
        op += op * 0.1;
        //alert("here");
    }, 10);

    }

</script>


</html>
```

Problem is that it fades and doesn't come back.

Comment: I suggest just trying something. The cool thing is that experimentation in this arena costs you nothing but your time. If you can't get it to work then post what you tried and ask for help.

Comment: I added the functions to a test code and made a border around a button that's part of a blockquote so i could see the test. The blockquote will fade, but since i added the button to the blockquote it disappears as well with the blockquote, but it doesn't come back even though i put both the functions in the button. I was hoping the button would come back so i could keep re-clicking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually need something like 'fade toggle', so, both, fade-in, and fade-out should happen on one click. In that case, you don't need two functions, you can set additional `'flag'`, to check some conditions, and to set fade direction (increment or decrement of opacity).

E.g. in this case, if opacity is lower than 0.01 (if you check your op value, you will notice that it is not rounded, and maybe we don't need rounded value, we need to fade-out element completely, *so in few moments opacity should be ultra-low*), fade direction should be changed, so - you should increment opacity, and vice versa.

You could do something like this:

```
<blockquote id= 'fader'> 

        <input type = 'button' id = 'fades' value = 'This fades.' onclick = 'fade_toggle(this.parentNode,true);'/>

</blockquote>
```

JS:

```
function fade_toggle(el, check) {

  var op = 1; // initial opacity

  var timer = setInterval(function() {

    el.style.opacity = op;
    el.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
    if (op > 0.01 && check == true) {
      op -= op * 0.1;

    }

    if (op < 0.01) {

      check = false;

    }
    if (check == false && op < 1) {

      op += op * 0.1;

    }
    if (op > 0.9) {
      el.style.opacity = 1;
      check = true;
      clearInterval(timer);

    }
  }, 50);

}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/v386skuk/2/

Comment: Wow that is so much easier to follow than what i had. Two questions though, the this.parentNode is basically passing the blockquote element that the button is in?

And also there's one line that sort of confuses me a bit, because im not sure what it's saying:
 el.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
What does this line mean exactly?

Comment: @dragon123, yes. However, you can define target element how you want... I just used that, as simpler/faster....

Comment: That line is there for old, old IE's... Think that IE8 and above should work without it (not sure, you can check it).... Yes, as i thought: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-opacity/ IE9 and upper doesn't need filter prefix....

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for the helpful tips!